# ActiveMQ - Update on Connect?

Tags: activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, stomp

I'm working with ActiveMQ to implement some notification solutions in the emergency management / public safety sphere.  Right now I'm setting up a topic to move updates to an OpenLayers map using Stomp over websockets.

My question is... is there a way to ensure that each consumer gets the most recent message on connect?  I have it in mind to push updates every fifteen seconds or so, but I'd like folks to get the latest update when they connect and not have to wait till the next scheduled push.

Anything is possible, of course, so I guess my question is "is that feasible without a lot of pain?"

TIA,

Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a durable subscription but this backup all messages sent when consumer is offline, you can setup the expiry time for messages to be short to be discarded when consumer reconnect or use the retroactive consumer http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html

Comment: The beginning of wisdom is calling things by their proper name! ;-)  However... I'm not clear on how a Stomp-over-Websockets consumer (in JS in a browser) would declare itself retroactive.  Any hints?  Thanks!

Comment: OK, think I found it.  In the SUBSCRIBE message I need to add a header for activemq.retroactive.  Now I need to look at my .js library to see how to do that.